# How do I Install this ceiling light?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light

How do I install this ceiling light? I thought the previous ceiling light had the live wire connected to the group of two wires and the neutral wire connected to the single black wire. I tried to reconnect my new light like the last one and it did not work. When the power is on, the group of three wires are hot, but the two whites wires and the single black wire are not. Can someone please help explain what I am connecting incorrectly?

Pictures of the light and wires: https://imgur.com/a/Ghns8fo

Comment: By power on do you mean the breaker is on?  If so, then the single black should only be hot with the switch on.  The three wires are hot with the breaker on.

Comment: Yes, I meant the when the breaker was on, the group of three wires are hot, but the two white wires and the single black wire are not, even when the switch is turned on. Maybe this suggests the switch is disconnected somewhere?

Comment: With the breaker off pull the switch out and check the wires.  Might be a bad switch.  Take pictures before removing any wires.

Answer (score 2):

Well first, that goes back to whatever mail order seller sold it to you cheap, for a full refund. That fixture is not safe or legal to sell or use here. (NEC 110.2 and various FTC regs).  And then don't buy electrical equipment mail order anymore. The business practices of certain very large companies [and how they interact with 3rd party sellers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCTiU2ZHVwI) have created a flood of dangerous junk - e.g. the plastic it's made of is not fire-safe, and an electrical hotspot will turn into a plastic fire. Plastic is basically petroleum, and needs costly doping to be fire-safe(r).

And as you can see for yourself, the mounting plate is incorrect for the North American market.

Shopping at bricks-and-mortar shops is most reliable. (or their web outlets, but make sure that item is also sold in their stores: Sears and Walmart, for instance, blend in eBay and Amazon Marketplace results, which are more of the same junkstream mentioned earlier).  Make sure the item has the UL, CSA or ETL mark.

However, your wiring looks normal enough for an old-school switch loop, so I imagine you were paying attention when you took the old lamp off. Two blacks and a white, all of which are always-hot; two whites which are neutral, and a solitary black which is switched-hot.  You got the wires right, and thank you for not taking it all apart and "trying everything" - that destroys the identifying information I just stated.

So either the new lamp is defective or 220V (no great surprise), or the wiring was defective before you changed the old lamp (perhaps the reason you changed the old lamp?)

I would get a listed lamp from a reputable bricks-and-mortar supplier, not least it'll fit properly to that junction box.  If that doesn't work, wired like you have it, I'd next look at the wiring at the switch.  Should be black and white from one cable on the two switch terminals. This cannot work with a smart switch that requires neutral.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the single black should be the switched hot and the two whites should be neutral. None the less, the wiring looks correct. You should try reconnecting the old light; maybe the new one is bad. Otherwise, check all of the connections - maybe a wire came loose under a wirenut.

By the way, the new light looks like Chinese junk. I don’t see a UL or any other approval sticker. Did you buy it off of Amazon, eBay or some other reseller site? I’d return it and get something legitimate that is less likely to burn your house down.